# function min in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

i use the Mathematical function "min" in my Kotlin code to declare a variable "toRemove"

```
val toRemove = min(preferredQuantity - taken, stock.quantity)
```

> error message : Kotlin unresolved reference

1/ may i know how could i solve it?

2/ the function is within kotlin.math, why I cannot use it directly?
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/

Thanks!

Comment: Did you import it? `import kotlin.math.min`

Comment: it works now :) does it mean that, next time when i wanna use fun log, just add "import kotlin.math.log"? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, or if you're using multiple different math functions you can import them all with `import kotlin.math.*`. And in the future, if you don't remember the package of a function, you can click on it and press Alt + Enter to open a suggestion box for what to import (in Intellij IDEA or Android Studio).

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake: as pointed out by @Tenfour04 in the comments, make sure that `kotlin.math.min` is imported by checking that one of

```
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlin.math.*
```

is on top of the file. The `kotlin.math.*` variant will import everything from the [`kotlin.math`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/) package. See the Kotlin documentation page on [imports](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/packages.html#imports).